# ¿Cómo prevenir SQL inyección en Visual Basic .Net?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Estoy aprendiendo en Visual Studio - Visual Basic y con una base de datos SQLite.

En un formulario con 3 combobox logro guardarlos en la base de datos usando

```
sql = "INSERT INTO actos (parteA, tipo, parteB) "
sql += String.Format("VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", cboParteA.Text,     cboTipo.Text, cboParteB.Text)
```

Según leí ese método expone mi base de datos a ataques por inyección de SQL y para evitarlo debo usar Prepared Statement Object pero no me doy cuenta como aplicarlo en mi caso y la documentación en http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html es muy engorrosa.

Debo usar algo del estilo:

```
this.command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO actos (parteA, tipo, parteB)     VALUES(@param1, @param2, @param3)";
this.command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
this.command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", cboParteA.Text));
this.command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", cboTipo.Text));
this.command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@param1", cboParteB.Text));
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el problema. ¿Aparece algún error? ¿Es un problema de sintaxis en Visual Basic? ¿Es un problema en SQLite? ¿El "estilo" que publicas es tu código real o es un ejemplo genérico copiado de la documentación oficial de SQLite? Revisa [esta guía](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y edita lo necesario de tu pregunta para que expreses el problema real que enfrentas. Decir "no lo entiendo" no aclara nada.

Comment: visual studio es el IDE. Tu pregunta **no tiene que ver con el IDE EN ABSOLUTO**. En su lugar, coloca el lenguaje de programación en el que trabajas como parte de las etiquetas. Adicional a ello, parece que utilizas C#, de ser así me pregunto por qué revisas la documentación de C cuando C y C# son dos lenguajes completamente distintos.

Comment: @toledano el problema es claro y conciso: cómo evitar ataques de Inyección SQL en el código. El primer fragmento de código muestra código vulnerable a Inyección SQL y el OP pregunta cómo se puede corregir eso (eso es lo que no entiende).

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Exacto Luiggi, gracias por la aclaración. Soy nuevo en stackoverflow y todavía estoy entendiendo como se plantean las preguntas pero las orientaciones que me dieron me ayudan mucho. Ya se que no debo usar el primer tipo de solución y debo aprender como se resuelve esa grabación en la base de datos por el otro método. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exacto para evitar la inyeccion de dependencias debes usar parametros, si revisa la doc de la wiki

[Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

veras que hacia el final comenta como evitar esto en .net

La estructura de tu codigo debrias lucir como esto

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = "INSERT INTO actos (parteA, tipo, parteB) VALUES(@param1, @param2, @param3)";  
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", cboParteA.Text);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboTipo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboParteB.Text);     

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  

}
```

como veras si la libreria lo permite usa el AddWithValue() es mas simple de asignar

Comment: muchas gracias por la orientación me sirvió mucho. Estoy adaptando el código y solucioné varios problemas pero me da un error indicando "Insuficientes parámetros proveidos al comando". Creo que el lío viene porque no puedo aplicar la línea "SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn); " pues me da error y trato de dividirla en dos líneas independientes. Voy a tener que abrir otra pregunta para definir mejor el problema.
El enlace es:  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14941/visual-net-sqlite-insertar-datos-da-error-porque-falta-un-par%C3%A1metro

Comment: Lo que yo te recomendaría es que uses Procedimientos Almacenados desde tu Base de datos y los uses desde tu Vb, eso evita los ataques de Inyeccion Sql además que tu código se ve más ordenado, te dejo un link: http://goo.gl/9OVrmt