# Visual Net - SQlite - Insertar datos da error porque falta un parámetro

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

En [¿Cómo prevenir SQL inyección en Visual Basic .Net?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14890/c%C3%B3mo-prevenir-sql-inyecci%C3%B3n-en-visual-basic-net) consulté acerca de como prevenir ataques por inyección SQL.

Ahora estoy intentando grabar en la base de datos usando parámetros pero me da un error diciendo que no indiqué la cantidad suficiente de parámetros.

Mi código actual es:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BaseDatos.sqlite;Version=3")

Dim cmdGuardar As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

Try
Using (conn)

conn.Open()
sql = "INSERT INTO actos (parteA, tipo, parteB) VALUES(@param1, @param2, @param3)"
'Línea que debería usar pero me da un error
'SQLiteCommand cmd = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)
'Así que pruebo dar la misma instrucción en dos líneas diferentes
cmdGuardar.CommandText = sql
cmdGuardar.Connection = conn
cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", cboParteA.Text)
cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboTipo.Text)
cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboParteB.Text)

cmdGuardar.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()

End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo deberia lucir como esto

```
Try
    Using  conn As New SQLiteConnection("connstring")

        conn.Open()
        sql = "INSERT INTO actos (parteA, tipo, parteB) VALUES(@param1, @param2, @param3)"
        Dim cmdGuardar As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)
        cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", cboParteA.Text)
        cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboTipo.Text)
        cmdGuardar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", cboParteB.Text)

        cmdGuardar.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

la idea es definir la conexion y el command lo mas local posible

Comment: Correcto!! Incluso yo en realidad definía las variables por encima del cabezal del Form para que el ámbito de las mismas fuera todo el formulario pero por algún motivo no las tomaba. La solución final que tomé fue crear variables conn2 y sql2 dentro del Sub del botón y ahora funciona. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirve mucho para aprender. Ahora con un ejemplo funcional puedo seguir adelante. Saludos

Comment: Te recomendaría que uses Procedimientos Almacenados desde tu base de datos, y luego solo usarlos desde Vb, es más ordenado y seguro con lo Inyeccion Sql. Te dejo un Link: http://goo.gl/9OVrmt